# on-prem server and connect the node with the integration runtime in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, gateway, azure-data-factory

I wanted to pull the data from my on-prem server ( hive or oracle ) to Azure data factory. Whereas i am facing issues can you help me in this?

I am asking this on the basis of enterprise issue. I wanted my integration Runtime to be in Onprem server , currently we are installing it in our own laptops and if our laptop is shut down then obviously IR is stopped and data won't be loaded this can't be feasible in production.

Do anybody know that what is meant installing IR in my on prem server? that means in my hive server?

Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your SHIR server does not have to be on the same server as your data source. But it should be close to it. Same region or same data center.

You need a server that is always powered and running. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory).

If you want high availability you should refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#high-availability-and-scalability).

If you want DR, you will need another SHIR on a DR server in your secondary region.

You can also install the SHIR onto a VM running on the cloud. But your Onprem network needs to be connect to the Cloud VNET using Express route or a VPN.

Laptops is fine for testing but as you said, not for production.

Your IT team should also take care of the patching and updates/maintenance of the new server whether it is on prem or on cloud.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the response ,
i have commissioned the windows server to manage virtual servers or database servers. Once i get that should i install and configure my SHIR normally just like we do in our own laptop ?

Comment: The installation is exactly the same. You may just need whitelisting to be done in uour corporate network. Else ADF will not be able to reach your SHIR.

Comment: hi , 
i installed everything but when i am creating my linked service in Azure ( opening it throw my virtual server only i am getting below error. do u have any idea?
how we have to enable SSL ? 
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][DriverSupport] (1110) Unexpected response received from server. Please ensure the server host and port specified for the connection are correct and confirm if SSL should be enabled for the connection.